# Is it possible to debug shaders in GLSL level instead of assembly language level?

Tags: shaders, glsl, debugging, vulkan

I'm writing some Vulkan code and write my shaders in GLSL.

I tried to use Renderdoc to debug my shaders, but I only got disassembly code.

Is it possible to debug shaders at the level of GLSL if I have the source code of the shaders in GLSL format?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, as the main author Baldur Karlsson explicitly states in the tracking GitHub issue:

> Currently the debugging is primarily at SPIR-V level, not source language level

[Vulkan Shader Debugging tracking issue · Issue #1908 · baldurk/renderdoc](https://github.com/baldurk/renderdoc/issues/1908)

You *can* use the `OpSource` SPIR-V instruction to include the source language text in the shader module, at which point the `Source Unavailable` button becomes a clickable `Debug in Source` button,
but at this point it just doesn't (and isn't supposed to) work; stepping seems to jump all over the place.

Though it might be worth mentioning that including the source language text with `OpSource` enables you to use RenderDoc's shader editing feature which allows you to directly edit the GLSL code and immediately see the result in the texture viewer. (Use `glslang::TIntermediate::addSourceText` if you're compiling with glslang.)